# Identify and replace selective space inside given text file

Tags: sed

I am new to sed and its functioning. I need to selectively replace space with "," in a file where the content of the file is as follows. I do not want replace space inside "" but all the other spaces needs to be replaced.

File Content

```
my data "this is my very first encounter with sed"  "valuable" - - "c l e a r"
```

Used Pattern
using sed to replace space with "," - Patten is 's/ /,/g'

Actual Output

```
my,data,"this,is,my,very,first,encounter,with,sed",,"valuable",-,-,"c,l,e,a,r"
```

Expected Output

```
my,data,"this is my very first encounter with sed",,"valuable",-,-,"c l e a r"
```

Comment: While it is "possible" in sed, don't. Write a proper CSV parser in a different easier programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sed script with comments with input from bash here string:

```
<<<'my data "this is my very first encounter with sed"  "valuable" - - "c l e a r"' sed -E '
    # Split input with each character on its own line
    s/./&\n/g;
    # Add a newline on the end to separate output from input
    s/$/\n/;
    # Each line has one character
    # Add a leading character that stores "state"
    # There are two states available - in quoting or not in quoting
    # The state character is space when we are not in quotes
    # The state character is double quote when we are in quotes
    s/^/ /;
    # For each character in input
    :again; {
        # Substitute a space that is not in quotes for a comma
        s/^  / ,/

        # When quotes is encountered and we are not in quotes
        /^ "/{
            # Change state to quotes
            s//""/
            b removed_quotes
        } ; {
            # When quotes is encountered and we are in quotes
            # then we are no longer in quotes
            s/^""/ "/
        } ; : removed_quotes

        # Preserve state as the first character
        # Add the parsed character to the output on the end
        # Preserve the rest
        s/^(.)(.)\n(.*)/\1\3\2/;
        # If end of input was not reached, then parse another character.
        /^.\n/!b again;
    };
    # Remove the leading state character with the newline
    s///;
'
```

outputs:

```
my,data,"this is my very first encounter with sed",,"valuable",-,-,"c l e a r"
```

And a oneliner, because who reads these comments:

```
sed -E 's/./&\n/g;s/$/\n/;s/^/ /;:a;s/^  / ,/;/^ "/{s//""/;bq;};s/^""/ "/;:q;s/^(.)(.)\n(.*)/\1\3\2/;/^.\n/!ba;s///'
```

I think a newline `\n` in `s` command replacement string is an extension not required by posix. Another unique character may be used instead of a newline to separate input while parsing. Anyway I tested that with GNU sed.

Comment: wrt `I think a newline ...` - the only 2 seds that have a `-E` arg are GNU and OSX/BSD, the former will work with `\n`, the latter won't, so yes it's GNU sed only. There's almost certainly other GNU-isms in there too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is something better suited for an actual CSV parser instead of trying to kludge up something using regular expressions - especially `sed`'s rather basic regular expressions.

A one-liner in `perl` using the useful [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module (Install through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client):

```
$ perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new(sep_char=>" ", out_sep_char=>",")->write' < input.txt
my,data,"this is my very first encounter with sed",,valuable,-,-,"c l e a r"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^ ]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} 1' file
my,data,"this is my very first encounter with sed",,"valuable",-,-,"c l e a r"
```

Your input is a CSV where `C` in this case means "Character" instead of the traditional "Comma" and where the Character in question is a blank and you're just trying to convert it to a Comma-separated CSV. See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information on what the above does and on parsing CSVs with awk in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS="\""} NR%2 {gsub(" ",",")} {print}' file
```

- At the beginning, set the double quote as the record separator.
- For odd records, i.e. outside quotes, replace globally any space with comma.
- print every record.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^((("[^"]*")*[^" ]*)*) /\1,/;ta' file
```

Replace, the group of zero or more double quoted strings followed by zero or more non-space characters zero or more time followed by a space with the group followed by a comma, repeated until failure.